# Rails3.1 engine: can't get SLIM or HAML to work in test/dummy app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml, rails-engines, slim-lang

I'm developing a Rails 3.1 engine, and to integration test it I want to use SLIM instead of plain ol' ERB. So I tried to simply add `s.add_development_dependency "slim"` to my `.gemspec` file, but when renaming my `index.html.erb` file to `index.html.slim`, Rails complains:

> Missing template dummy/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/josh/Documents/Work/Sientia/iq_menu/full/spec/dummy/app/views" * "/Users/josh/Documents/Work/Sientia/iq_menu/full/app/views"

I tried it also with the `slim-rails` gem and also with the `haml-rails` gem, but there renaming the file to `index.html.haml` resulted in the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Haml you have to put

```
gem 'haml-rails'
```

into your Gemfile

Comment: Thank you, this works. Still, I'm a bit confused: in Yehuda Katz' Post [Clarifying the Roles of the .gemspec and Gemfile](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/) he mentions that when developing a gem, the Gemfile "a gem’s Gemfile should contain the Rubygems source and a single gemspec line". Why's it different here?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Do you want to develop a gem? Or just use the haml gem? For just using HAML you only need the haml-rails gem and not haml and haml-rails

Comment: I'm developing a gem using Rails 3.1's `rails plugin new my_engine` command.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, this is an old problem, but I ran into the same thing today (this time on Rails 4), and I think I can clarify the problem, here.

Bundler serves two roles -- one is to fetch the gems and make their code available, the other is to actually "require" that code into your project.

When you add a dependency into your gemspec, it does the first function, but not the second.

In production use of your application, the dependencies identified by your gemspec are effectively added to the application's bundle, so the application's bundler will both fetch and require your gems.

If you only have the reference in the gemspec, and not in your Gemfile, then effectively nothing is doing the require, so the gem doesn't get initialized and the template engine isn't made available to your application. Adding it to the Gemfile makes it get initialized and registered.

I think you need both, for something like slim/haml. Just having the Gemfile reference means the application won't know about the dependency, and just having the gemspec reference means the engine doesn't get initialized in your dummy app.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the standard `haml` gem, but in your `engine.rb` you need to have:

`require 'haml'`

Comment: I thought it was automatically required, it isn't at least in the case of an engine